# Leaflet Routing Machine - update/redraw route

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I'm new about Laflet Routing Machine (liedman) https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/ and I would like to update the first route calculated every 30 seconds because I would like refresh it and I don't need to make many server request.

I'll make a setInterval but at the moment I need to know if it works and if this is the way... this is my code:

```
routingControl = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(43.12, 11.99),
        L.latLng(43.37, 12.08)
    ]
    createMarker: function() { return null; },
    routeWhileDragging: false,
    draggableWaypoints: false,
    reverseWaypoints: false,
    fitSelectedRoutes: true,
    addWaypoints: false
}).addTo(OSM_Map);

var newLat = routingControl.options.waypoints[0].lat+0.01;
var newLng = routingControl.options.waypoints[0].lng+0.01;
setTimeout(function () {
   routingControl.options.waypoints=[
       L.latLng(newLat, newLng),
       routingControl.options.waypoints[1]
   ];
}, 10000);
```

With setTimeout I change the start point (adding 0.01) and checking the waypoints with console.dir they are changed but not the drawn route... how I can refresh it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options are only used when initializing the routing control. Changing them afterwards does nothing, since the control uses its own waypoints internally.

You should be able to use the `setWaypoints` function like this

```
setInterval(function () {
    var newWaypoint = routingControl.getWaypoints()[0].latLng;
    var newLat = newWaypoint.lat + 0.01;
    var newLng = newWaypoint.lng + 0.01;
    routingControl.setWaypoints([
       L.latLng(newLat, newLng),
       routingControl.options.waypoints[1]
     ]);
}, 10000);
```

Unlike the options, the getWaypoints always returns the current waypoints, so you can freely modify them.
setWaypoints will then trigger a change event for the routes and update them accordingly.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://codepen.io/curtisy1/pen/poWOoJp) you can play around with